# cannot create view in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have a simple query like this:

```
select d.file_name, d.tablespace_name, s.segment_type, s.segment_name,
round(s.bytes/1024/1024,2) MB
from dba_data_files d
inner join user_segments s on d.tablespace_name = s.tablespace_name;
```

It works fine. But what i really want is to create a view with this query.
So i put:

```
create view espaco as
select d.file_name, d.tablespace_name, s.segment_type, s.segment_name,
round(s.bytes/1024/1024,2) MB
from dba_data_files d
inner join user_segments s on d.tablespace_name = s.tablespace_name;
```

But it doesnt work, it says:

> ERROR at line 4:
>
> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

So, how come I can do this query normally, but if I create view it doesnt work?
I can create other views, but when I create a view to search from `dba_data_files` it doesn`t work.
The user has create view privileges, dba privileges, any privileges, and still doesnt work.
Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you don't have direct access to the dba views and have it granted through a role. You can check out this answer on Stack Overflow for a little more information.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936449/grant-create-view-using-system-view-with-dba-privilage-in-oracle

Comment: Thanks Joe, I looked at this post u refered, it was spot on.